# Reference book on Backward Martingale theory

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

I am looking for an introduction to the topic of  BACKWARD MARTINGALES  possibly with good intuition (it can  be either notes or a book) AND a reference book on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-070j-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT15_070JF13_Lec11Add.pdf
2. http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~ps422/mynotes.pdf
3. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Probability-Martingales-Cambridge-Mathematical-Textbooks/dp/0521406056

3 is a book for reference; 1 and 2 are pdfs/notes...